# Why can't I suggest an edit to the Kindle tag?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I am trying to suggest an edit to the [kindle](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle) tag, but every time I visit this URL:

> https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1

...I am redirected to this URL:

> https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/tags/kindle/info

Am I doing something wrong? I can suggest edits to other tags no problem.

Comment: There is a pending edit. Maybe you have to wait until it is approved?

Comment: Only Stack Exchange staff would be able to approve it (none of us have anywhere near enough rep.), so there's not much anybody can do then.

Comment: Quick, give me upvotes, and I will take care of it. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a pending edit to that tag wiki.  I approved it and then your suggestion, which was slightly more detailed.